Chrome DevTools Network tab change display 5000 ms
Chrome DevTools Network tab display is 5000 ms currently (attach screenshot).
How to zoom in or make the display setting from 5000 ms to a smaller value such as 10 ms?
I followed wOxxOm's great advice by dragging the gray handles.
I can zoom into 100 ms only (attach second screenshot).
How to zoom in a smaller value such as 10 ms?


The numbers on the top won't change until you reload the page. You can use mousewheel on the strip below Overview or drag the gray handles to zoom in on an interval.
